# Using .CSV file as an external dictionary, but can't find a way to reference/make a key for Null in order to assign it a value using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, csv, null, dictionary

I am using ArcGIS Desktop: ArcMap 10.8.1 and using Python 2.7.18. I have a script that uses a .CSV file as an external dictionary (opposed to creating a dictionary within the script) but I cannot find a way to reference/make a key for Null in order to assign it a value.

My .CSV is formatted as followed:

| Species | Scientific | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Malus pumila | DECID |
| Bur Oak | Quercus macrocarpa | DECID |
| Null | x | x |

And here is the code snippet:

```
with open(trees_csv, mode='r') as tree_dictionary:
    csvreader = csv.reader(tree_dictionary)
    next(csvreader)
    scientific_species = {}
    tree_type = {}
    for coloumn in csvreader:
        scientific_species[coloumn[0]] = coloumn[1]
        tree_type[coloumn[0]] = coloumn[2]
with da.UpdateCursor(points, fields) as tree_cursor:
    for row in tree_cursor:
        row[1] = scientific_species.get(row[0], '')
        row[5] = tree_type.get(row[0], '')
        tree_cursor.updateRow(row)
```

No matter how I try to reference Null in my .CSV, I keep getting blanks in the attribute table opposed to 'x'.

Therefore, in what way can I get my dictionary to recognize Null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little long for just a comment.

If I were you:

I would first check you dictionary and make sure it is as it should appear by just simply printing it the console.

If it looks right, then the next point would be look at the `get()` functions. `get()` essentially does a comparison for the key and optionally returns a value if the key doesn't exist. I would focus here since you seem to suggest the rest of the fields fill correctly.

Compare the null value you have in your dictionary to the value in your dataset. Is the case the same? You don't do any case conversion before comparing values? `"null" != "Null"`

Speaking of strings, are you trimming out any whitespace? If it is human entry, especially on touchscreen devices, extraneous whitespace is a problem and sometimes hard to find. Good case for why you should use domains in your attributes.

Finally are you comparing the string `"Null"` to the Python object `None`? If your attribute field is actually null, that being: there is no value in the field, then the return value of the row's element will be the object `None`. The `None` object is not the same as `"Null"`. `"null" != "Null" != None != "None"`

If your are actually comparing to None you can instead do:

```
with open(trees_csv, mode='r') as tree_dictionary:
    csvreader = csv.reader(tree_dictionary)
    next(csvreader)
    scientific_species = {}
    tree_type = {}
    for coloumn in csvreader:
        scientific_species[coloumn[0]] = coloumn[1]
        tree_type[coloumn[0]] = coloumn[2]
with da.UpdateCursor(points, fields) as tree_cursor:
    for row in tree_cursor:
        row[1] = scientific_species.get(row[0], 'x')
        row[5] = tree_type.get(row[0], 'x')
        tree_cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Where the `get()` does all the work by automatically inserting the "x" when it encounters the `None` object, empty field, as you step through the rows. Though, with this, any entry not included in the dictionary will also have an "x" assigned.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth reply! Please allow me to elaborate: the dictionary, as you caught on, fills in perfectly except for attributes that have <Null>. The 'Species' field in the attribute table has a domain, and the dictionary corresponds to that fields' domain (collectors can only pick pre-determined entries). Therefore, no trimming is needed and all keys match the entries within the attribute table. All Null entries in the attribute table look like this: <Null>; I have tried many keys to try and reference <Null>, such as: None, <Null>, '', "", etc. Nothing seems to pick it up.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, your suggestion worked! I appreciate the time to took to think through many different scenarios and provide explanations/solutions to each one. Using `row[1] = scientific_species.get(row[0], 'x')` and `row[5] = tree_type.get(row[0], 'x')` is exactly what I was looking for, to be honest. I would prefer to see any values not in the dictionary assigned with 'x'. Thank you so much, @RomaH!

Comment: Great! I think it was ArcMap that used a grey, italicised 'null' in a field with no value, made it more apparent that it was just a placeholder text, not actually the string "<Null>". Null values can be tricky and it doesn't help that ArcGIS and Python use different words for the same idea.